# how can i decrease my balance with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web

so i have the parking system with PHP-MySQL project. there are 2 table, mahasiswa and dataparkirs. the mahasiswa have 1 field name 'saldo' it means the balance of user to park the vehicle. so when the vehicle is parking out the balance in table mahasiswa, which name is 'saldo' is cut by 3000 constantly.

so i had to fil the value of saldo to 8000. how can i write the formula to cut the balance in saldo is decrease by 3000 constantly?

```
<?php
     
    require 'database.php';


    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        
        // keep track post values
        ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Jakarta');
        $no_kartu = $_POST['no_kartu'];
        $jam_keluar = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $status = 'keluar';
        $saldo = $_POST['saldo'];
        $tarif = 3000;
        $total_bayar = $saldo - $tarif;

        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        $sql = "UPDATE dataparkirs SET jam_keluar = '$jam_keluar', status = '$status' WHERE no_kartu = $no_kartu ";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($jam_keluar,$status));

        $sql = "UPDATE mahasiswa SET saldo = '$total_bayar' WHERE no_kartu = $no_kartu ";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($total_bayar));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: parkirmasuk.php");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please share more details. For example, is this code really related to [tag:rfid] or [tag:parking]? What's your exact question about this? Also, please do never use string concatenation to build SQL queries

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound/excuted queries

Answer (score 0):

***This code needs debugging.***

Check for `$POST['saldo']` value first, you are not fetching it from the database in this code, it could be a null value on the first hand.

Thus, for

```
$total_bayar = $saldo - $tarif;
```

Check for the subtracted value. This is where the `$saldo` is 0 and `$tarif = 3000;` (hardcoded)

***Thus giving $total_bayar as -3000***

NOTE:

Your prepared statements are incorrect. Use `?` or `:total_bayar` instead of variables in direct string. Have a look here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php